# Which shortcut to capture the screenshot in an adjacent display other-than the primary?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, multiple-monitors, keyboard-shortcuts

Or rather, Which shortcut or key combination can allow one to capture the screenshot in an adjacent display (monitor or projector) other than the primary (say the main desktop)?

So, I have two monitors - the one on the laptop, and another on an extra monitor attached to the laptop. Am running Window 10, and using an HP laptop. So, I use the  [prt sc] and can save the current screenshot of the laptop's display only.

I tried to move the mouse cursor into the adjacent display (am running in screen-extension, not replication mode), however, with that display "active" thus, using the print screen function still only captures the main display!

So, how to solve this Gates folks?

Comment: btw my hp laptop can take screenshot by only the prt-sc key....no need to press fn key...try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your cursor should be on the display that you want to screenshot.
  Press CTRL, ALT, and PrtScn together.
- Tip 1: press ALT + PrtScn to take screenshot of only the active window, this should also be a solution for you.
- Tip 2: To save yourself the time to first press print screen key then go to any application such as paint or word and then paste it there and then save it...simply press Windows key + printscreen, your screenshot will get saved to Pictures > Screenshots
- Ctrl+Prt-sc will take screenshot of both screens

Comment: was this not the solution for you ??

Comment: However, with the [WinKey+PrtScn] approach, the screenshot spans both displays. What I wanted was the same auto-save behavior of that key combination, but for the adjacent display - which I regard to be the "active one" since the cursor is in that display (am I right?)

Comment: Actually, I find that the desired behavior (see comment above) can be achieved with a combination of [Alt+WinKey+PrtScn] however, the screenshots are intercepted by some XBox Console Companion tool, and not shows in the Pictures folder as the other command does!

Comment: You can also try the Snipping Tool. Shortcut: Win key+Shift+S , then mark the area and then paste it.

Comment: So, looks like I wasn't yet a win10 su %-)